# result getting zero while converting oracle datetime value into second in php

Tags: php, oracle, strtotime

here is the code first

```
$sql = 'SELECT DATETIME, CURRVALUE FROM DATEVALUE';
$stid = oci_parse($conn, $sql);
oci_define_by_name($stid,'DATETIME', $agev);
oci_define_by_name($stid,  'CURRVALUE', $snv);
oci_execute($stid);
$resultXML = new SimpleXMLElement(stripslashes('<data></data>'));
while (oci_fetch($stid)) {  
      $agev = oci_result($stid, 'DATETIME');
    $snv = oci_result($stid, 'CURRVALUE');
     //settype($agev, "string"); 
    $date_2 = strtotime($agev);
    settype($date_2, "integer"); 
     //settype($snv, "float");  
    $temp = $resultXML->addChild('node'); 
    $temp->addChild('agev',$date_2);
    $temp->addChild('snv',$snv); 
} 

<node>
<agev>0</agev>
<snv>1</snv>
</node>
```

result for currvalue is good but for datetime value it output zero only,
if i do addtimevalue without using strtotime it will output datetime in string but its not what i need....
please helppppp ~.~

Comment: Show us the format that it output from DATETIME when you don't try to convert it with `strtotime`. There are other functions for converting date values. We could help with this additional information.

Comment: in sybase it works fine, is it because its different in oracle? :D

Comment: Why are you doing stripslashes on a string constant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two ways that could help fix the problem.

*First (possibly better) way: Change your SQL query.*

Have Oracle output the date using a different format, one that `strtotime` will recognize. If DATETIME is a normal date-type column in your database, consider using the `TO_CHAR` Oracle function to change its output format. Something like:

```
$sql = "SELECT TO_CHAR(DATETIME, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS DATETIME, CURRVALUE FROM DATEVALUE";
```

*Second way: use `strptime`.*

Instead of using `strtotime`, consider using [strptime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strptime.php). The date format you show in your comments appears to be close to:

```
%d-%b-%y %H.%I.%S %p
```

I'm not sure if there's a date format option for the milliseconds part. Assuming it will parse it correctly without that, changing the line:

```
$date_2 = strtotime($agev);
```

to:

```
$date_2 = strptime($agev, '%d-%b-%y %H.%I.%S %p');
```

should do it. You'll still get an error, though, if my assumption is wrong.

Comment: thx for the inspiration! im still getting errors like "define not done before fetch or execute and fetch " or "table or view does not exist in", ill trying figure out in those two ways .thxxx again :D

Comment: @user987013, now I'm confused. those error messages were not included in your original question.

Comment: You need an underscore between the "TO" and "CHAR" parts of the TO_CHAR function call. Additionally, I'm not sure why you're using two different tables. In the question your table was called DATEVALUE, but apparently that does not exist? Use the table T00000000_01080413 if that's where your data is located.

Comment: now problem solveeedddddd ! it now outputing in second format like such<agev>1317722050</agev>. thx so much again :D :D